# Como funciona a remoção de árvore Binária em C

Tags: c, árvore-binária

Estou com diversas dúvidas no funcionamento de arvore binária em C.

Estou com um código e estou com dúvida de como funciona a remoção na árvore. Alguém poderia me explicar melhor o que está acontecendo em cada linha na parte da remoção?

### Struct

```
struct No{
    int numero;
    struct No *esquerda;
    struct No *direita;
};
typedef struct No No;
```

### Inserção

```
void inserir(No **pRaiz, int numero){
    if(*pRaiz == NULL){
        *pRaiz = (No *) malloc(sizeof(No));
        (*pRaiz)->esquerda = NULL;
        (*pRaiz)->direita = NULL;
        (*pRaiz)->numero = numero;
    }else{
        if(numero < (*pRaiz)->numero)
            inserir(&(*pRaiz)->esquerda, numero);
        if(numero > (*pRaiz)->numero)
            inserir(&(*pRaiz)->direita, numero);
    }
}
```

### Remoção

```
No *MaiorDireita(No **no){
    if((*no)->direita != NULL) 
       return MaiorDireita(&(*no)->direita);
    else{
       No *aux = *no;
       if((*no)->esquerda != NULL) // se nao houver essa verificacao, esse nó vai perder todos os seus filhos da esquerda!
          *no = (*no)->esquerda;
       else
          *no = NULL;
       return aux;
       }
}

No *MenorEsquerda(No **no){
    if((*no)->esquerda != NULL) 
       return MenorEsquerda(&(*no)->esquerda);
    else{
       No *aux = *no; 
       if((*no)->direita != NULL) // se nao houver essa verificacao, esse nó vai perder todos os seus filhos da direita!
          *no = (*no)->direita;
       else
          *no = NULL;
       return aux;
       }
}

void remover(No **pRaiz, int numero){
    if(*pRaiz == NULL){   // esta verificacao serve para caso o numero nao exista na arvore.
       printf("Numero nao existe na arvore!");
       getch();
       return;
    }
    if(numero < (*pRaiz)->numero)
       remover(&(*pRaiz)->esquerda, numero);
    else 
       if(numero > (*pRaiz)->numero)
          remover(&(*pRaiz)->direita, numero);
       else{    // se nao eh menor nem maior, logo, eh o numero que estou procurando! :)
          No *pAux = *pRaiz;     // quem programar no Embarcadero vai ter que declarar o pAux no inicio do void! :[
          if (((*pRaiz)->esquerda == NULL) && ((*pRaiz)->direita == NULL)){         // se nao houver filhos...
                free(pAux);
                (*pRaiz) = NULL; 
               }
          else{     // so tem o filho da direita
             if ((*pRaiz)->esquerda == NULL){
                (*pRaiz) = (*pRaiz)->direita;
                pAux->direita = NULL;
                free(pAux); pAux = NULL;
                }
             else{            //so tem filho da esquerda
                if ((*pRaiz)->direita == NULL){
                    (*pRaiz) = (*pRaiz)->esquerda;
                    pAux->esquerda = NULL;
                    free(pAux); pAux = NULL;
                    }
                else{       //Escolhi fazer o maior filho direito da subarvore esquerda.
                   pAux = MaiorDireita(&(*pRaiz)->esquerda); //se vc quiser usar o Menor da esquerda, so o que mudaria seria isso:
                   pAux->esquerda = (*pRaiz)->esquerda;          //        pAux = MenorEsquerda(&(*pRaiz)->direita);
                   pAux->direita = (*pRaiz)->direita;
                   (*pRaiz)->esquerda = (*pRaiz)->direita = NULL;
                   free((*pRaiz));  *pRaiz = pAux;  pAux = NULL;   
                   }
                }
             }
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa é uma árvore binária que guarda inteiros em nós intermediários, além das folhas, e com a propriedade de que todos os números na subárvore esquerda de um determinado nó são estritamente menores que o número do nó. Números iguais ou maiores ficam na subárvore direita.

Então vamos lá:

```
void remover(No **pRaiz, int numero){
```

A função de remoção recebe um ponteiro para um ponteiro para um nó; isto é necessário caso o número a ser removido (listado no segundo parâmetro) seja encontrado no próprio nó raiz: neste caso, o endereço de `pRaiz` tem que mudar para a função que chama `remover()`.

A primeira coisa que se faz é testar para ver se a árvore está vazia, e se estiver, terminar:

```
    if(*pRaiz == NULL){   // esta verificacao serve para caso o numero nao exista na arvore.
       printf("Numero nao existe na arvore!");
       getch(); // getch() é fogo, mas tudo bem
       return;
    }
```

Apesar de ele escrever uma mensagem de "erro", isto é um comportamento correto. Se você manda remover um elemento que não existe de uma estrutura, ele não faz nada, e você pode assumir que aquele elemento não existe mais na estrutura. Se ele existia antes ou não, não faz diferença.

Em seguida, ele compara o número para saber em que sub-árvore ele está. Para isto, ele testa um conjunto de condições em ordem, e vai descartando as possibilidades metodicamente. Pessoalmente, eu não faria este tipo de indentação e manteria tudo no mesmo nível, mas vamos explicar o código que existe, não o que eu escreveria:

O primeiro caso é se o número procurado é menor que o número do nó atual:

```
    if(numero < (*pRaiz)->numero)
       remover(&(*pRaiz)->esquerda, numero);
```

Se for, ele deve estar, por construção, na subárvore esquerda. Executamos, então, o mesmo algoritmo recursivamente na subárvore esquerda.

Se não for, então verificamos se o número procurado é *maior* que o número atual. Se for, ele estará na subárvore direita, e executamos o algoritmo recursivamente na subárvore direita.

```
    else 
        if(numero > (*pRaiz)->numero)
            remover(&(*pRaiz)->direita, numero);
```

Finalmente, tendo eliminado a possibilidade de o número ser maior ou menor, concluímos que o número está localizado na raiz desta árvore. Então `pRaiz` é o nó a ser removido! Procedemos, portanto, com o processo de remoção:

```
        else{    // se nao eh menor nem maior, logo, eh o numero que estou procurando! :)
```

Primeiro criamos uma variável auxiliar para manipular os nós. O comentário se refere ao fato de compiladores que não atendem ao padrão C99 exigirem que **todas** as variáveis locais sejam declaradas no princípio das funções. É o que eu normalmente faço por portabilidade, mas outros não gostam...

```
            No *pAux = *pRaiz;     // quem programar no Embarcadero vai ter que declarar o pAux no inicio do void! :[
```

Agora tratamos o caso de `pRaiz` ser uma folha, isto é, não tem filhos nem à esquerda, nem à direita. Neste caso, é só apagar o nó e correr para o abraço:

```
            if (((*pRaiz)->esquerda == NULL) && ((*pRaiz)->direita == NULL)){         // se nao houver filhos...
                free(pAux);
                (*pRaiz) = NULL; 
            }
```

É claro, a probabilidade de o nó ser uma folha é baixa; neste caso, você tem que lidar com as subárvores. Um dos nós vai ter que substituir esse nó que você está apagando, e as subárvores vão ficar penduradas nesse novo nó.

Esse novo nó tem que ser ou o maior número da subárvore esquerda, ou o menor número da subárvore direita. Ele começa tratando os casos em que ou um, ou outro é nulo: neste caso, basta substituir o nó com a subárvore que existe.

```
            else{     // so tem o filho da direita
                if ((*pRaiz)->esquerda == NULL){
                    (*pRaiz) = (*pRaiz)->direita;
                    pAux->direita = NULL;
                    free(pAux); pAux = NULL;
                }
                else{            //so tem filho da esquerda
                    if ((*pRaiz)->direita == NULL){
                        (*pRaiz) = (*pRaiz)->esquerda;
                        pAux->esquerda = NULL;
                        free(pAux); pAux = NULL;
                    }
```

Neste caso, o final e mais complicado, o item tem filhos em ambos os lados. Aí não basta simplesmente substituir o nó por uma das duas árvores, você tem que escolher ou o maior nó à esquerda ou o menor nó à direita do cara que você quer apagar. No caso, o autor escolheu o maior nó à esquerda. Ele então "dá um passo à esquerda" e vai descendo a árvore à direita até encontrar um nó que não tenha subárvore direita. Isso foi encapsulado na função `MaiorDireita()`.

Depois disso, ele pega a subárvore direita do nó e pendura na direita da nova raiz; e o mesmo com a subárvore esquerda. Depois é só destruir a antiga raiz e retornar.

```
                    else{       //Escolhi fazer o maior filho direito da subarvore esquerda.
                        pAux = MaiorDireita(&(*pRaiz)->esquerda); //se vc quiser usar o Menor da esquerda, so o que mudaria seria isso:
                        pAux->esquerda = (*pRaiz)->esquerda;          //        pAux = MenorEsquerda(&(*pRaiz)->direita);
                        pAux->direita = (*pRaiz)->direita;
                        (*pRaiz)->esquerda = (*pRaiz)->direita = NULL;
                        free((*pRaiz));  *pRaiz = pAux;  pAux = NULL;   
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

No caso do `MaiorDireita()`, o que ele tem que fazer é pegar uma árvore (que vai ser a subárvore esquerda de um nó que queremos apagar), e ir descendo para a direita até não conseguir mais. O nó onde pararmos é o nó que queremos retornar, mas antes precisamos removê-lo da árvore.

Note que ele, por construção, não tem uma subárvore direita, mas pode ter esquerda. Neste caso, vamos fazer como fizemos no caso análogo na `remover()` e substituí-lo pelo seu filho esquerdo. Agora que ele está fora da subárvore e não tem mais filhos pendurados nele, pode ser retornado para substituir o raiz acima:

```
No *MaiorDireita(No **no){
```

Começamos andando recursivamente à direita até não podermos mais;

```
    if((*no)->direita != NULL) 
       return MaiorDireita(&(*no)->direita);
    else{
```

Não podendo andar mais à direita, guardamos uma referência ao nó que vamos retornar;

```
        No *aux = *no;
```

Pegamos a subárvore esquerda do nó, se houver, e a colamos no lugar do nó atual;

```
        if((*no)->esquerda != NULL) // se nao houver essa verificacao, esse nó vai perder todos os seus filhos da esquerda!
           *no = (*no)->esquerda;
        else
           *no = NULL;
```

E retornamos o nó.

```
        return aux;
    }
}
```

A `MenorDireita()` é igual, *mutatis mutandis*.

Comment: você teria algum código com explicação mais fácil?

Comment: Qualquer código que faça o que esse código faz não será _muito_ mais simples que isso. Existe um limite mínimo de complexidade para uma dada tarefa. Mas talvez a explicação seja muito verborrágica, aí você poderia apontar as partes que estão confusas para eu tentar melhorar...

Answer (score 0):

Você está a remover um valor dentro de uma árvore binária de busca (ele sempre mantém a ordenação após a remoção, então necessariamente ela está ordenada). Dê uma lida no [artigo de árvore binária de busca da Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria_de_busca#Remo.C3.A7.C3.A3o), vai ajudar seu entendimento.

Esses diversos `if`s e `else`s aí estão para testar como será feita a reinserção dos valores filhos do nó. Por exemplo, ele verifica se é uma folha (caso **Remoção na folha**):  não precisa reinserir nada; se ele possui apenas um único filho (caso **Remoção de nó com um filho**): reinsere a subárvore no lugar do nó removido; se ele possui dois filhos (caso **Remoção de nó com dois filhos**): nesse caso, ele coloca o menor elemento filho do nó removido em seu lugar (igual ao [exemplo da Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria_de_busca#Remo.C3.A7.C3.A3o_de_n.C3.B3_com_dois_filhos)).

A estrutura de dados árvore binária funciona igual em toda e qualquer linguagem de programação escolhida. Em algumas, você terá de adaptar o conceito de objeto e métodos de acesso para o paradigma procedural (**C**), enquanto outras você pode manter perfeitamente o uso como tipo abstrato de dado (**Java**, **Python**, **C++**). Dependendo do paradigma, você pode escrever mais ou menos, pode ser mais ou menos flexível, mas a ideia central é a mesma em todas elas.